# How to update CLOB column from a table to another table using dblink in a trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, clob, dblink

I have 2 tables in Oracle databse, one of them which I'm trying to update is on another database connected using a dblink. In my tables there are two columns of type CLOB. I am writing a trigger in one database that should update the new CLOB columns' values to the remote table on the remote database. When I want to update the Clob columns I get the following error:

SQL Error: ORA-02055: distributed update operation failed; rollback required
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SPECTRA.REPORT_UPDATE'
02055. 00000 -  "distributed update operation failed; rollback required"
*Cause:    a failure during distributed update operation may not have
rolled back all effects of the operation.  Since
some sites may be inconsistent, the transaction must roll back to
savepoint or entirely
*Action:   rollback to a savepoint or rollback transaction and resubmit

How can I update the values of CLOB columns in a remote database?

Comment: I know this is not possible and can be done via using `global temporary table`. You could really search for it in AskTom or over Google :) but right now I have a [link](https://www.dba-village.com/village/dvp_forum.OpenThread?ThreadIdA=79323) which can be useful.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 
Do you have a working code example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use DBMS_LOB package ? i.e. functions

```
  DBMS_LOB.COPY (
  dest_lob    IN OUT NOCOPY BLOB,
  src_lob     IN            BLOB,
  amount      IN            INTEGER,
  dest_offset IN            INTEGER := 1,
  src_offset  IN            INTEGER := 1);
```

or

```
DBMS_LOB.COPY ( 
  dest_lob    IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB  CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,
  src_lob     IN            CLOB  CHARACTER SET dest_lob%CHARSET,
  amount      IN            INTEGER,
  dest_offset IN            INTEGER := 1,
  src_offset  IN            INTEGER := 1);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i997674

Or paste your code...

Comment: The following error occurs:
SQL Error: ORA-02055: distributed update operation failed; rollback required
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
ORA-06512: at "**", line 71
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '**'
02055. 00000 -  "distributed update operation failed; rollback required"
*Cause:    a failure during distributed update operation may not have
           rolled back all effects of the operation.  Since
           some sites may be inconsistent, the transaction must roll back to
           savepoint or entirely

Comment: My code is:
SELECT REPORT_TEXT_LOB INTO TARGET_R_TEXT FROM REPORT@BROKERLINK WHERE REPORT.REPORT_KEY@BROKERLINK = R_KEY FOR UPDATE;
       SELECT REPORT_TEXT_LOB INTO SOURCE_R_TEXT FROM REPORT WHERE REPORT.STUDY_KEY = R_KEY;
       DBMS_LOB.COPY (TARGET_R_TEXT, SOURCE_R_TEXT, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(SOURCE_R_TEXT), 0, 0);